# Make inline edit in wp_list_table

Tags: jquery, wp-list-table

I'm very new to JavaScript and jQuery. However, I've jumped into trying to make inline edit for my `wp_list_table` but find it difficult to catch the class for some reason.

The classes for the column I'm trying to catch is named

```
<td class="director column-director">
```

I've tried the 2 following statements below to check that I actually catch the class correctly:

```
$( ".director").click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});


$( ".director", '.column-director' ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

The console shows no errors and nothing is happening when I click the `<td>`.
Is there anyone that can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: replace `$( ".director", '.column-director' )` by `$( ".director, .column-director")`

Comment: Ty for the answer Karun now i know how to mark serval classes at once :)
but it did'nt work, konsol shows no errors and nothing happens when i press the td.

Comment: Is your table an Ajax return? I tested the jQuery code. It was ok. Anyways try replacing `$` by `jQuery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$( ".director", '.column-director' )` by `$( ".director, .column-director")` and also replace `$` by `jQuery`